What does tftp_server and tcpdump is used for in Xiaomi android phone?
I have a Xiaomi smartphone, the OS is Xiaomi HyperOS, which I believe is a variant of Google's vanilla Android OS. I used adb to open a shell, and found that there are two "suspicious" processes tftp_server and tcpdump running all the time:
vendor_rfs    1779     1 0 20:50:18 ?     00:01:42 tftp_server
system        2289     1 0 20:50:19 ?     00:00:45 tcpdump -i any -W 3 -C 5 -s 134 -w /data/vendor/wlan_logs/tcpdump.pcap -Z system

I know tftp service is usually for firmware upgrade in embedded systems, and tcpdump is for capturing packets, especially when debugging code related to network protocols.
What is the purpose of these 2 processes?

First questions: Did you buy the device new, in its sealed box? Are you confident that the device is running the OS it was shipped with? Please add answers to your posting.

The phone is brand new, I bought in shanghai from an authorized retailer.
